# sharepoint. Remove item in job is event will be called

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

I remove list items inside SharePoint job. 
But I cannot get it why events are not rised in my event recievers. Is it some SharePoint feature or just bug? When I remove items from web interface all events are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remmeber events fire in all cases. Make sure your event listeners are installed in the GAC, not to bin folder of the Web application - timer jobs are running in separate process and may not be able to find your assemblies with receivers. Also check SharePoint logs for any errors...